# Ratchet push messaging without implementing WampInterface

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I want to implement MessageComponent interface and push notification.(The tutorial in ratchet has WampInterface for push). 
I do not want to use WampInterface as it is in v1 and there are no libraries for that version for iOS.

I am using this in Laravel, and this was my first try:

```
 $loop   = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

        $class = $this->option('class');

        $ratchetServer = new $class($this);

        $this->info(sprintf('Starting ZMQ server on: %s:%s', config('ratchet.zmq.host'), config('ratchet.zmq.port')));

        $context = new \React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
        $pull = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
        $pull->bind(sprintf('tcp://%s:%d', config('ratchet.zmq.host'), config('ratchet.zmq.port')));

         $pull->on('message', function($message) use ($ratchetServer) {
             $ratchetServer->onEntry($message);
         });


        $webSock = new \React\Socket\Server($loop);
        $webSock->listen($this->port, $this->host);
        $webServer = new \Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
            new \Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
                new \Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                    new PusherServer()
                )
            ),
            $webSock
        );

        return $loop;
```

I have a pusher server where I will be handling my own 'topics' and clients.

An example that I tried(that doesn't work) to push data from server to some topic:

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
        $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, null);
        $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
        $socket->send("this is the message");
        $socket->disconnect("tcp://localhost:5555");
```

How do I make push notification work (my server should be able to send message to client) without implementing WampInterface (and just MessageComponentInterface)

Comment: I think you might have the wrong tag for your question... doesn't ratchet implement `websockets` (a specific protocol) rather then raw `sockets`?